# Problems creating symfony form using persisted entity with manyToMany relation as data

Tags: forms, symfony

I have two entities for which I have built form types.

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('createdAt')
            ->add('updatedAt')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('plainPassword')
            ->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('phoneNumber')
            ->add('address')
            ->add(
                'roles',
                'collection',
                array(
                    'type' => new UserRoleType(),
                    'data_class' => 'Mrm\AuthBundle\Entity\UserRole',
                    'required'     => false,
                    'allow_add'    => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Mrm\AuthBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mrm_authbundle_user';
    }
}
```

And

```
class UserRoleType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('createdAt')
            ->add('updatedAt')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('label')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Mrm\AuthBundle\Entity\UserRole'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mrm_authbundle_user_role';
    }
}
```

As you can probably guess, there is a ManyToMany relation between User and UserRole.

If I try to submit new data, **everything works perfect**. Both User and UserRole entities are created and also the ManyToMany relation corespondent entries.

```
$manager = $this->get("doctrine.orm.entity_manager");

$user = new User();

$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $manager->persist($user);
    $manager->flush();
} else {
    return View::create($form, 400);
}
```

But when I try to implement some logic to support updates, like this (Note that code is for test purpose and id is hardcoded..)

```
$manager = $this->get("doctrine.orm.entity_manager");

$repo = $manager->getRepository("MrmAuthBundle:User");    

$user = $repo->find(6);

$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $manager->persist($user);
    $manager->flush();
} else {
    return View::create($form, 400);
}
```

**I get** "`**The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Mrm\AuthBundle\Entity\UserRole, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of Mrm\AuthBundle\Entity\UserRole.**`" error.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hello Michael,
is the User class inherited from FosUserBundle User class?

Comment: Hi Airam, no, it just implements UserInterface